# HtmlWebpackPlugin: could not load file favicon.ico?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: `index.html`
        template: `public/index.html`,
        favicon: "../public/favicon.ico",
        name: 'index',
        inject: true
    })
```

Why is HtmlWebpackPlugin not loading the file `favicon.ico`?

Comment: new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: `index.html`
        template: `public/index.html`,
        favicon: "public/favicon.ico",
        name: 'index',
        inject: true
    })

Answer (score 3):

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: `index.html`
    template: `public/index.html`,
    favicon: "public/favicon.ico",
    name: 'index',
    inject: true
})
```

The relative path to the `.ico` file was wrong.